# x509: certificate is valid for *.transperfect.com, transperfect.com, not auth.docker.io

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

When I want to login in docker with this command:

```
docker login -u "username" -p "password"
```

this error occurred:

> Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/":
> Get
> "https://auth.docker.io/token?account=alizne&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=registry.docker.io":
> x509: certificate is valid for *.transperfect.com, transperfect.com,
> not auth.docker.io

How can I resolve this problem?

I try with a vpn, but this problem was not resolved!